# Sorting a struct with sub-structs in Swift

Tags: swift, sorting, struct

I have the below structs in my project:

```
struct templateScheduleResponse: Decodable {
    let templateScheduleTypes: [scheduleTemplateType]
}

struct scheduleTemplateType: Decodable {
    let templateScheduleNames: [templateScheduleName]?
    let templateTypeId: String?
    let templateTypeName: String
}

struct templateScheduleName: Decodable {
    let templateNameId: String?
    let templateSchedName: String
}
```

and I want to sort it so that the array of templateScheduleName is sorted by templateSchedName value.

I'm completely stuck on how to do this.

Any pointers, please? (I'm just started learning Structs, if you couldn't tell!)

Thanks!

UPDATE: Here is my JSON data:

```
{
    templateScheduleTypes =     (
                {
            templateScheduleNames =             (
                                {
                    templateNameId = "fad562bc-4510-49ea-b841-37a825a2f835";
                    templateSchedName = "Daily_Intensive";
                },
                                {
                    templateNameId = "fdeeb79f-6321-4ff6-b1f0-8272a018e73b";
                    templateSchedName = "Weekly_Full_Log_Directories";
                },
                                {
                    templateNameId = "84f9800f-da18-44b8-822f-830069dcc594";
                    templateSchedName = "Weekly_Full";
                },
                                {
                    templateNameId = "47a6f050-13d7-4bf6-b5db-ab53e0a3aa54";
                    templateSchedName = "Weekly_Full_Catalog_Two_Weeks";
                },
                                {
                    templateNameId = "b8ef9577-e871-4d79-8d3a-cfe958c0c3aa";
                    templateSchedName = "Weekly_Full_Over_WAN";
                },
                                {
                    templateNameId = "8d507f52-0d74-404e-ad0d-76e6a7a94287";
                    templateSchedName = "Monthly_Full";
                }
            );
            templateTypeId = "4e73b9ea-71d0-4abd-83c6-7d7b6d45641b";
            templateTypeName = datalist;
        },
                {
            templateScheduleNames =             (
                                {
                    templateNameId = "39386552-45a5-4470-b152-7be00583e767";
                    templateSchedName = "Scheduled_Exchange_Server";
                }
            );
            templateTypeId = "a7c28240-c187-4f86-818c-efd86fb26c7d";
            templateTypeName = MSESE;
        },
                {
            templateScheduleNames =             (
                                {
                    templateNameId = "0037846c-d1fe-4c8f-8eec-c62681a12a57";
                    templateSchedName = "Scheduled_Exchange_Single_Mailbox";
                }
            );
            templateTypeId = "9e06f06a-11dc-44b8-97a0-68bd0b45a07a";
            templateTypeName = Mailbox;
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do an ad hoc sort without having to conform to Comparable. If x is some variable of type templateScheduleType:

```
x.templateScheduleNames.sorted(by: { (lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
    return lhs.templateSchedName < rhs.templateSchedName
})
```

If you want to ensure the array is sorted in place at construction time, define an init method on scheduleTemplateType just as you would on a class:

```
init(scheduleNames: [templateScheduleName], typeID:String?, typeName:String) {
   self.templateScheduleNames = scheduleNames.sorted(by: { (lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
        return lhs.templateSchedName < rhs.templateSchedName
    })
   self.templateTypeId = typeID
   self.templateTypeName = typeName
}
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks. This looks more promising with the init method. But the sort order still doesn't seem right, it comes out like: http://imgur.com/a/WJrN7

Answer (score 1):

First of all struct names should begin with an uppercase char.

To answer your question, you need to make `TemplateScheduleName`

```
struct TemplateScheduleName: Decodable {
    let templateNameId: String?
    let templateSchedName: String
}
```

conform to `Comparable`

```
extension TemplateScheduleName: Comparable {

    static func ==(lhs: TemplateScheduleName, rhs: TemplateScheduleName) -> Bool {
        return lhs.templateSchedName == rhs.templateSchedName
    }

    public static func <(lhs: TemplateScheduleName, rhs: TemplateScheduleName) -> Bool {
        return lhs.templateSchedName < rhs.templateSchedName
    }
}
```

Now given

```
let list : [TemplateScheduleName] = []
```

you can easily sort it

```
let sortedList = list.sorted()
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I have a list of TemplateScheduleResponse (the top struct), how do I sort the oder within that of the schedule names?

Comment: I would not conform to comparable. `sorted` can just take in a closure anyway, and there's no reason to infer that this sorting criteria can define equatability